# how to hide main grid columns inside nested grid using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

how to hide main grid columns inside nested grid using jquery?

I have a main grid inside that two subgrids,I want to hide only columns from main grid only.no need to hide it from subgrid

Comment: Please provide your html snippet to let others help you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
   $('#gvSalesInvoiceSearch>tbody> tr').each(function () { if (i != 2) { $(item).children("th:eq(" + i + "), td:eq(" + i + ")").hide(); } var a = $(item).children("td:eq(" + i + ")").text(); if (a == "Total") { $(this).hide(); } });
```